# Importing using package prefix does not work in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on the line that gives error for importing, there is no available import as something like:

`import: 'package:client/ui/custom/widgets/loading_image_placeholder.dart`

What is the solution for that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem recently,

1- check your pubspec yaml with get packegs again & restart your pc

If it still doesn't work

2- create a new project and move your lib to it

(This problem occurred with me when I get project files individual)

Answer (score 0):

Dart guidelines suggests to use [relative paths within your own package's lib directory](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-relative-paths-when-importing-libraries-within-your-own-packages-lib-directory).

I assume, you use *Android Studio*. If I am right, go to *File*, click *Invalidate Cache / Restart* and select *Invalidate and Restart*. It removes local history of the project, but it helps with 99% issues like yours.

If it doesn't help, answer to the following questions:

1. Do you use symlinks in that project?
2. Have you changed your package name during development?
3. What is the `flutter doctor -v` output?